# Extracting density function (risk neutral)

Tags: r

Im using R to calculate the risk neutral probability implicit in option prices. Im using function 'extract.shimko.density' ("RND" package), but getting the following error when I execute the function:

```
Error in uniroot(f, lower = lower, upper = upper, maxiter = 5000) :
f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

In addition:

```
Warning messages: 1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :   
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 2: 
In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :   
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code and reproduce the error you are getting. That will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: @MrFlick  - below are details of a sample data: Sample data can be found at http://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/datamine-historical-data/files/e-mini%20s%26p%20options%2010-01-2012.csv

Comment: Contract month is  'te', Settlement is 's0' and strike price is 'k'.Rest of the required variables are constants except call.price which is call.price = price.bsm.option(r=r, te=te, s0=s0, k=k, sigma = sigma, y = y)$call.  Im getting the 'uniroot' error (as mentioned in my first post) when I attempt to run functions like 'extract.shimko.density' or 'compute.implied.volatility' in the RND package. The error appears when I execute the function in a loop.

Comment: The error appears for these functions: compute.implied.volatility(r=r, te=te, s0=s0, k=k, y=y, call.price=call.price, lower=lower, upper=upper) and also for extract.shimko.density(market.calls=call.price,call.strikes=k,r=r,y=y,te=te,s0=s0,lower=-10,upper=10). I can't figure out how to deal with the uniroot error.

Comment: Would be really great if someone could help!